# How to shift element upwards to it's variable height using css

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, markup

## Main question

I have two divs, one nested inside the other and i wish to shift inner div outside (upwards) of outer div and slide-in it on a hover.

Markup is looking like so:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="inner">Green is variable-height text which slides in on viewport hover</div>
    Blue is a viewport (&lt;body&gt;, visible part of a page), which content should be compressed upon green slide-in
</div>
```

And (a little pseudo) css:

```
.body {
    background: #aaf;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner, .body:hover .inner {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.2s;
    transition:all linear 0.2s;
}

.inner {
    background: #afa;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top:-some-magic-to-get-this-div-height;
}

.body:hover .inner {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

And a final result animation i'd like to get, without using fixed height of green div:

[image: example.gif]

Also, this example (with a guessed and hard-coded height value of 2.5em) on jsfiddle to experiment with:

http://jsfiddle.net/n7vyLoh4/20/

## Possible partial work-around (not satisfactory)

It is possible to partially implement what i want, using transitioning max-height instead of transitioning margin-top, the transition of `max-height: 0;` **->** `max-height: 100%;` with `overflow: hidden;` set at all times
works, but has two draw-backs:

1. it doesn't slide in, it's more like drops the curtain
2. it doesn't stop transition at the end of green div, it transits till the end of outer blue div, which especially noticeable at reverse transition, when it first travels all the way from bottom of blue div to bottom of green div before any effect is visible. Also, this means that despite transition time set to 0.2s, it will spend only fraction of this time on transiting trough green div, because this 100% are 100% of parent div, not inner one (and my question could be answered if there is a way to calculate the 100% of inner div height).

Here is an illustration:

[image: example2.gif]

And fiddle for that:

http://jsfiddle.net/bsd7vnwu/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the effect you want. CSS doesn't allow you to get the height of an element to use in `calc()` for positioning and margins, so a little JS is needed.

**CSS**:

```
.body {
    background: #aaf;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner, .body:hover .inner {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.2s;
    transition:all linear 0.2s;
}

.inner {
    background: #afa;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.body:hover .inner {
    margin-top : 0 !important;
}
```

**JS**:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('inner'), function (item) {
    item.style.marginTop = (item.clientHeight * -1) + 'px';
});
```

**Demo**:

http://jsfiddle.net/09tyLr9b/

Comment: Should be a real-world solution, doing things in time, thank you, +1. I am likely to accept your answer in 24h, if no CSS-only solution will be found for this period (as the use of JS while it wasn't mentioned in original question is not what i have expected and i am not lost all the hope finding pure CSS solution).

Comment: CSS is very limited in its abilities to figure stuff out. It's not really it's job, so feel relief in that you're simply asking too much of it.

Comment: You cannot accept this answer when you search for css only solution. If there is no css solution, than people must know that.

Comment: Yes, it is not a perfect pure-CSS solution, but it seems to be only one really working from the suggested, which is probably because i was too demanding with CSS indeed. Also, this answer contains the remark that pure CSS solution is not possible (maybe worth emphasizing it with <strong>; text style though), so accepting it wouldn't distract people from knowing there is no pure CSS solution (yet). And though i agree on overdemandive nature of my question, i still want to give it some time in thin hope it could be properly answered using some clever CSS trick i am not aware of.

Comment: @skobaljic did you really downvote me? Downvoting implies the answer is not useful, but it is, hence the working demo. If your answer is better, it'll get more upvotes and be accepted, but really save downvoting for blatantly incorrect answers.

Answer (score 5):

This is the pure `css` solution, which means **it does not require any scripts**, just a browser that support transitions:

```
.body {
    background: #aaf;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0,.81,.4,1) 0.5s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0,.81,.4,1) 0.5s;
}

.inner {
    background: #afa;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -100%;
    float: left;
}

.body:hover .inner {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

And Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n7vyLoh4/28/)

Comment: I am sorry, but it seems you are missing two crucial points: first one is that you're using `margin-top: -100%`, which is 100% of relative parent container, not inner, which makes green div to shift up way too above. The second point if that you (again, as in your previously deleted (why?) answer) trying to work-around this with custom easing curve. The problem with it is that it yes, could be tuned to match specific ratio of inner height to parent height, but not any height ratios in general, which makes it as good as guessing the height to be equal to 2.5em, only not as obvious.

Comment: It is not same and technique is not same. If you try and set -5em in your example than whole content would shift up. I deleted the answer because it does not provide pushing/sliding the content down initially. With this technique you can slide the content down no matter what the `inner` div height is, but transformation cannot go in reverse direction, because we change position to absolute.

Comment: My remarks are still valid: 100% is the 100% of relative parent, not inner div and custom curve will work precisely only when tuned to specific ratio of `parent height` / `inner height`, not for every ratio which is possible by changing inner div height in `0..parent div height` boundaries. And if we know the `inner height` so we can compute and hard-code a curve, we may instead just hard-code a negative `margin-top`, which would be much simpler, straight-forward and not outside the flow as it is with `position: absolute`.

Comment: It is irrelevant where the inner element is hidden, animation finishes in exactly .5 seconds and that will be same for all elements with same class. User is not aware of where the hidden element is, they will only see how the animation finishes. For the other part, I see you still think margin percentage is based on parent height, which is not true - when using margin or padding percents for height it is based on parent element width instead. Since we do not know inner height, it is fluid, than there is no way to set negative margin to exact height (but that is not important for our animation)

Comment: Yes, animation ends in 0.5 seconds, but speed for the element to travel in exactly 0.5 seconds may vary depending on distance between it's starting position and destination. Thats obvious. If not, try placing it in -9999px away and -9px away and you see the difference in it's appearance with naked eye. I am, on other hand, not looking for approximate solution with easing curve tuned to one specific approximate position, i need rather precise one.

Comment: If element heights are different, than speed must differ too, even in your favorite javascript solution here. You also claim same above.

Answer (score 3):

I added `transition` to your fiddle to get what i think you are looking for

```
.inner {
    background: #afa;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition:0.5s ease-out;
}

.body:hover .inner {
    max-height: 100%;
    transition:0.5s ease-in;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bsd7vnwu/2/)

and by lowering the time for `transition:ease-out` you will get a more responsive slide up when you mouse out of the `div`

like this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bsd7vnwu/5/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a very precise solution, it will not be possible to match the animation easing curve (even if you use bezier) to varying height of green div without calculation of actual height of this div (which, if possible, could lead to a much simpler solution with negative margin-top), sorry

Comment: @AlexanderTumin ahh k let me think a sec

Answer (score 2):

Another CSS solution after 2.5 years, using [flex layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes):

```css
.body {
    background: #aaf;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) 0.5s;
    transition: all cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) 0.5s;
    background: #afa;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.body:hover .inner {
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class="inner">Green is variable-height text which slides in on viewport hover</div>
    Blue is a viewport (&lt;body&gt;, visible part of a page), which content should be compressed
```

Also on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7vyLoh4/63/).

Comment: Nice solution. Though it still requires `.body` (parent container) to have a defined `height`. If `height` isn't defined, there is no animation at all: https://jsfiddle.net/v8b9tnc3/1/ .

Maybe someone has an idea how to get rid of this annoyance?